# Why heat flow perpendicular to the isothermal surface?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

I was reading Feynman-Leighton-Sands 's physics lecture note in Volume 2 chapter 2 when deducing the equation $$h = -k\ \text{grad}T$$

It seems we use the assumption that **heat flow orthogonal to the isothermal surface.**

Which I find is not mentioned in the book,so I find a post [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/67783/264677),I'm not sure whether this point corresponds to the sentence "but for many metals and other substances that conduct heat is quite accurate"

But I find a proof for this fact [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/67474/264677)

> Finally, heat flux is normal to a isothermal surface, because if it wasn't it would have a tangential component along the isothermal surface at that point.

Hence we can deduce that if we assume that isothermal surface has constant thermal energy,we must has  heat flow orthogonal to isothermal surface correct?

I mean isothermal surface may not have constant thermal energy in general correct?

Comment: An isothermal surface is one on which the temperature is the same on the entire surface. Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. So clearly you can not have a component of energy transfer in the form of heat along an isothermal surface.

Comment: @Bob D thanks  Why https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/67783/264677 this post state it does not hold in general then?

Comment: It seems in the book we first define heat flow as the change of thermal energy through the surface unit per unit time(which does not correspond to the temperature),then deduce the relation between heat flow and change of temperature?So we need to prove the statement "Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference" ?How to prove it?

Comment: In general, the heat flux vector does not have to be parallel with the the temperature gradient For crystalline solids the conductivity $\kappa$ is a tensor that can be non-diagonal and thus there can be tangential component to the heat flux vector.

Comment: @hyportnex what does tensor here means a (0,0) tensor?isothermal surface may not have constant thermal energy in general correct?

Comment: i do not understand your question.

Comment: @hyportnex I mean in the proof "heat flux is normal to a isothermal surface"  :if it wasn't it would have a tangential component along the isothermal surface at that point. and we know definition of heat flow $h$ is $h = \frac{\Delta J}{\Delta a} e_f$ with non zero tangential component then means exist termal energy chang on the isotermal surface

Comment: Forget the word "tensor". Just think of $\kappa$ a $3\times 3$ matrix whose elements depend on the crystalline class. The various elements describe the dependency of the direction of the thermal flux on the direction. Since a crystal is not "truly" homogeneous with respect to direction you can expect that heat flux depend on it just like light when as it refracts in a crystal.

Comment: "heat flux is normal to a isothermal surface" is not a "proof", it is an assumption here from which it follows that $\kappa$ is a scalar, or better said, it is $3 \times 3$  a diagonal matrix whose three non-zero elements are all equal.

Comment: @hyportnex But this https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/67474/264677 post proves it?And I think the proof is reasonable?

Comment: considering heat flux as energy transfer caused by temperature difference as @Bob_D wrote is still correct but one cannot simply deduce from that the scalar nature of conductivity unless one also assumes that the material is isotropic. Just as one cannot derive that in general the $h$ v. $\nabla T$ relationship is a linear one, a claim of course would not be true.

Comment: @hyportnex thanks but the logic seems differ from the textbook,which first define the heat flow using change of thermal energy then introduce the physical law between thermal energy and temperature $J= k(T_2-T_1)A/d$ to deduce the statement here " heat flux as energy transfer caused by temperature difference --- $h = -k \nabla T$" ?

Comment: replace $\Delta T = T_2-T_1$ with a differential $dT = \nabla T \cdot d\mathbf r$ and $J$ with $dj = \mathbf {h} \cdot d\mathbf{A}$

Comment: @hyportnex ,thanks maybe I don't  really understand this subject,can you recommend some alternative textbook that talk about heat transfer and related subject in a more mathematical way?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=tensorial+thermal+conductivity&sxsrf=ALeKk03aSybTbwuMgLhicy5DteGF23WxRw%3A1617121130701&source=hp&ei=ak9jYNbuJ6iRwbkP3KK08Aw&iflsig=AINFCbYAAAAAYGNdeo05yfX576vX4jWRYcYZodYlE6qn&oq=thermal+conductivity+tensor&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMYATICCAAyBggAEBYQHjoICAAQsQMQgwE6CwguELEDEMcBEKMCOgUILhCxAzoFCAAQsQM6AgguOggILhCxAxCDAToLCAAQsQMQgwEQyQM6BQgAEJIDOg4ILhCxAxDHARCjAhCTAjoFCAAQyQNQyBBYgjhgxFdoAHAAeACAAf0BiAG7FZIBBjIxLjUuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXo&sclient=gws-wiz

Comment: Sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The heat flux vector being proportional to the temperature gradient vector is an empirical observation applicable exclusively to isotropic materials (materials whose physical properties at a given location are independent of direction).  For anisotropic materials (such as crystalline materials or composites), the heat flux vector can have a component parallel to the local isotherms.

Your inclusion of the terms thermal energy and thermal energy change in this discussion make no sense to me, and are irrelevant as far as I am concerned.

Comment: thanks,does the definition of heat flux as $h = \frac{\Delta J}{\Delta a} e_f$ where $\Delta J$ as change of thermal energy per unit of time and $\Delta a$ is area of surface where $e_f$ is direction of flow correct? If so " heat flux vector can have a component parallel to the local isotherms."  implies can have thermal energy change on isothermal surface correct?

Comment: @ChetMiller isn't heat a transfer of energy due to a difference in temperature. If there is heat flux parallel to the isotherm then how is it heat since it is not driven by a difference in temperature. Is this using a different definition of heat?

Comment: @Dale I didn't say that the heat flux is parallel to the isotherm.  I said that the heat flux vector has a component parallel to the isotherm.  Suppose that the composite has highly conductive rods oriented at an angle to the isotherms.  Then the average of the rods plus matrix will have a component of heat flux parallel to the isotherms.

Comment: @Chet Miller  Does isotherm has different thermal energy on it?

Comment: @ChetMiller ah, ok I got it. A component of the flux can break the rule as long as the flux as a whole follows it. +1 for an answer that completely surprised me

Comment: @yili I've been doing heat transfer in real life practice for a long time, but I have no idea what you mean by an isotherm having thermal energy on it.  Can you define this in a precise way?

Comment: I was learning partial differential equation right now,So I read it to gain some intuition about the backgroud,I just 
treat thermal energy here as $E:\Bbb{R}^3 \to \Bbb{R}$.  If $h$ has component says $h_t = a e_t$ where $e_t$ parallel to is isotherm,which means $\Delta J \ne 0$ on it correct?

Comment: Sorry, I can't relate to this.  What is J supposed to represent?  And is E the internal energy per unit volume or per unit mass?

Comment: Sorry about that,I know nothing about this subject.Can you recommend some reference book about this subject ?

Comment: See Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot